# Passing Thread Properties in Taurus YAML JMeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, taurus

I am trying to build a Taurus yaml file for the below Jmeter scenarios, I have 2 threads where I am passing the Number Of Threads and Duration. Now with the regular command line, I use the below command to start the script, I use this same command from Jenkins too. This works fine and generate reports but not blazemeter one, so i am trying Taurus integration...

```
nohup /ssd/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter3g -Jquoteoff.threads=20 -Jquote.threads=20 -n -t /ssd/jmeter/scripts/PerformanceTesting/src/PS/OFFLINE_ONLINE.jmx
```

[image]

My below YML give me error, i am not sure if i am missing anything.
[image]

```
    execution:
- scenario:
    properties:
      quote.threads: 20
      quoteoff.threads: 20
      onduration: 3600        
    script: /ssd/jmeter/scripts/PerformanceTesting/src/PS/OFFLINE_ONLINE.jmx
```

Also is there any direct command like shell we can use to invoke this script? I have seen a few places directly calling JMX script in Jenkins but not sure how to pass parameters in that scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what's wrong here but below line is what causing the failure when i am trying to run `bzt script.jmx`

```
log.debug( vars.get("QUOTE_ID"));
```

To fix it when I changed `log.debug` to `log.info` it fixed the below problem I was facing. This is the partial answer as i am not sure about the reason for failure, but this should solve an issue where the script runs fine in Jmeter but bzt gives an error for XML parsing.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

0. Wouldn't that be easier to add [BlazeMeter Uploader plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/BlazeMeterUploader.md) to your JMeter test plan, the plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
1. It's possible to [run existing .jmx script](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) without creating any YAML

   ```
   bzt /path/to/your/test.jmx
   ```
2. The correct syntax to [define properties](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables) is:

   ```
   execution:
   - scenario: simple

   scenarios:
     simple:
       script: tests/jmx/dummy.jmx
       properties:
          quote.threads: 20
          #etc
   ```
3. Parameters can be passed via `-o` command-line argument[enter link description here](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/#Command-Line-Options-Override)

Comment: It's not free if you do it through JMeter, you only get the limited report. With Taurus integration it's free. Back to your 3rd point, i am confused how its formed lets say in my scenarios quote.thread is property i want pass value. What will be correct format if i send it via -o.. i see example like this but my scenario is not variable so confused.  modules.jmeter.path=alternate/jmeter/bin/jmeter